# How to create a SQL trigger to update a date field on one table when another table is updated

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

**I want to create a trigger in my database which should run when table 'Valve' is updated.**

As part of the trigger following must happen:

1. ME table should be created or updated as per the Schema of Valve table [PnPID, Position X/Y/Z, LineNumberTag, Tag, Spec.]
2. All information from existing table Valve, to be copied/updated into the table ME

The changes, should happen automatically in the table ME as per the source Valve without the need for any manual intervention.

Please help me create such a Trigger? I am new in SQL.

On my table ME.Valve I want to add other columns with new information that I do not want to appear in the Valve table (do not corrupt it). I attach a picture with existing table Valve.
So, what I want is to copy from tabel "Valve_PNP" in my tabel SQL_P3D_Test_ME for example only column "LineNumberTag" , "Tag", but when value from tabel "Valve_PNP" column "LineNumberTag" , "Tag" are changing, to change and into my tabel SQL_P3D_Test_ME automatically.
And in my tabel SQL_P3D_Test_ME add new column for exampe Made By in witch I insert information manualy in row in front of each valve.
It is possible?

This is what I want, in table "dbo.Source Tabel" you have one row in that you have information in columns "TextColumn", "ValueColumn" etc. For start this information will be copied in table [me].[Destination Table], but when information into tabel"dbo.Source Tabel" for example in column "TextColumn" change from "test insert and update with no data change" with "Marius", to update in tabel [me].[Destination Table] only this information and not add new row. And so on for each column.

[image]

I use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

[image]

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Most dbms products have their own, non-ANSI SQL, versions of triggers.)

Comment: Tables have _columns_, not fields...

Comment: I'm obviously missing the point here - what's the point in having two tables which always contain exactly the same data?

Comment: The obvious solution (based on your "answer" details below) is to just have the ME.Valve table and have a *view* called `Valve` that existing code continues to access and thinks is a table. Assuming a simple select in the view, it'll be updatable with no further work. Don't look to make work for yourself. Holding the same data multiple times just gives you opportunities for inconsistency.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and triggers are highly vendor specific) Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: @MariusDoman . . . This sounds like a really bad idea.  Please explain why you would create and copy a table like this.  It sounds like there was  a bad design decision somewhere.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff ...All the table (including Valve_PNP) that you see in picture are automatically generated from Autocad project that is stored on SQL.
My employer want to add new information through SQL Servver that will not appeare on dwg. file, and to not corupt the existing file I must create a new database in wich copy information from Valve_PNP(in this file are all information that I need), or copy from multiple tabel with are not _PNP.

Comment: @MariusDoman . . . Not at all.  You simply need another table that has the primary key of the `valve_pnp` table, so you can reference each row.

Comment: what you mean by primary key? I create another tabel(SQL_P3D_Test_ME), what should I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest adding the trigger to the "Valve" table that contains the update to the "ME.Valve" table.  Let me know if I should write a sample of the syntax.

Here's an example of my solution..

```
USE [SpecifyYourDatabaseHere]

CREATE TABLE dbo.SourceTable
    (
    SourcePrimaryKeyID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    TextColumn VARCHAR(2048),
    ValueColumn DECIMAL(18,3),
    NumberColumn INT
    )

CREATE TABLE [me].[DestinationTable]
    (
    DestinationPrimaryKeyID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    SourcePrimaryKeyID INT,
    TextColumn VARCHAR(2048),
    ValueColumn DECIMAL(18,3),
    NumberColumn INT,
    ActionType VARCHAR(100),
    CreatedDate AS GETDATE(), -- Default to current date
    CreatedDatabaseUser AS SUSER_SNAME()
    )

GO

-- You will need an insert, update and delete trigger.

-- INSERT TRIGGER

-- This trigger will insert any new records into the destination table.
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[SourceTable_Insert]
ON [dbo].[SourceTable]
FOR INSERT

AS 

INSERT INTO [me].[DestinationTable] 
    (
    SourcePrimaryKeyID,
    TextColumn,
    ValueColumn,
    NumberColumn,
    ActionType
    )
SELECT  INSERTED.SourcePrimaryKeyID,
        INSERTED.TextColumn,
        INSERTED.ValueColumn,
        INSERTED.NumberColumn,
        'Insert' AS ActionType
FROM    INSERTED

GO

-- UPDATE TRIGGER

-- Conditional Update Trigger : This trigger will only insert data in destination of any of the values in the data columns has changed (Saves space).
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[SourceTable_Update]
ON [dbo].[SourceTable]
FOR UPDATE

AS 

INSERT INTO [me].[DestinationTable] 
    (
    SourcePrimaryKeyID,
    TextColumn,
    ValueColumn,
    NumberColumn,
    ActionType
    )
SELECT  INSERTED.SourcePrimaryKeyID,
        INSERTED.TextColumn,
        INSERTED.ValueColumn,
        INSERTED.NumberColumn,
        'Update' AS ActionType
FROM    INSERTED
        INNER JOIN
            (
            SELECT  SourcePrimaryKeyID,TextColumn,ValueColumn,NumberColumn
            FROM    [me].[DestinationTable]
                    INNER JOIN
                        (
                        SELECT  MAX(DestinationPrimaryKeyID) MaxDestinationPrimaryKeyID,
                                COUNT(1) DestinationRecordCount
                        FROM    [me].[DestinationTable]
                                INNER JOIN
                                    INSERTED ON
                                        [me].[DestinationTable].SourcePrimaryKeyID = INSERTED.SourcePrimaryKeyID
                        GROUP BY
                            [me].[DestinationTable].SourcePrimaryKeyID
                        ) MaxDestinationPrimaryKey ON
                        MaxDestinationPrimaryKey.MaxDestinationPrimaryKeyID = [me].[DestinationTable].DestinationPrimaryKeyID
            ) DestinationData ON
                DestinationData.SourcePrimaryKeyID = INSERTED.SourcePrimaryKeyID
                AND (
                        ISNULL(DestinationData.TextColumn,'') != ISNULL(INSERTED.TextColumn,'') OR 
                        ISNULL(DestinationData.ValueColumn,0) != ISNULL(INSERTED.ValueColumn,0) OR 
                        ISNULL(DestinationData.NumberColumn,0) != ISNULL(INSERTED.NumberColumn,0)
                    )

GO

-- DELETE TRIGGER

-- This trigger will insert any deleted records into the destination table.

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[SourceTable_Delete]
ON [dbo].[SourceTable]
FOR DELETE

AS 

INSERT INTO [me].[DestinationTable] 
    (
    SourcePrimaryKeyID,
    TextColumn,
    ValueColumn,
    NumberColumn,
    ActionType
    )
SELECT  INSERTED.SourcePrimaryKeyID,
        INSERTED.TextColumn,
        INSERTED.ValueColumn,
        INSERTED.NumberColumn,
        'Delete' AS ActionType
FROM    INSERTED

GO

-- Test the code..

-- Insert trigger 
INSERT  [dbo].[SourceTable]
SELECT  'test insert and update with no data change',
        123.456,
        1

INSERT  [dbo].[SourceTable]
SELECT  'test insert and update with data changed',
        123.456,
        1

INSERT  [dbo].[SourceTable]
SELECT  'test delete',
        123.456,
        1

-- Update trigger test 1 - no data changed (Must not add record in destination)
UPDATE  [dbo].[SourceTable]
SET     NumberColumn = 1
WHERE   SourcePrimaryKeyID = 1

-- Update trigger test 2 - Data changed (Must add record in destination)
UPDATE  [dbo].[SourceTable]
SET     NumberColumn = NumberColumn + 1
WHERE   SourcePrimaryKeyID = 2

-- Deleted trigger test
DELETE FROM [dbo].[SourceTable]
WHERE   SourcePrimaryKeyID = 3

SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.SourceTable

SELECT  *
FROM    me.DestinationTable
ORDER BY
        SourcePrimaryKeyID,
        DestinationPrimaryKeyID
```

Comment: if you are kind you can write a sample of the syntax.

Comment: Hi Marius, unfortunately I realised that the requirements you have can not be done with just a trigger.  Triggers are used to run SQL code against update, insert or delete actions of data inside a table.  Although it can be virtually any code, a trigger will take care of replicating data from the one table to the other.  It is not ideal for scenarios when there are structural changes involved (For example columns added).

Comment: The columns we want to add will be informative and will be completed manually at the end of the project.
You want to tell me I can not add columns after trigger is made? Thanks!

Comment: No. That all depends on what the trigger does. In your question you stated that the column changes needs to be applied by the trigger to the other table (which has other columns that must not affect the source table). That will be challenging.

Comment: So, what I want is to copy from tabel "Valve_PNP" in my tabel SQL_P3D_Test_ME for example only column "LineNumberTag" , "Tag", but when value from tabel "Valve_PNP" column "LineNumberTag" , "Tag" are changing, to change and into my tabel SQL_P3D_Test_ME automatically.
And in my tabel SQL_P3D_Test_ME add new column for exampe Made By in witch I insert information manualy in row in front of each valve.
It is possible?

Comment: This is very similiar to something I have on a system that I develop on... We have a database with tables containing production data that can be changed.  We also have an audit database that keeps a log of any changes made to data in the production table. This Audit DB has identical tables (Including COLUMNS) but with additional columns ADDED for primary key and to record the datetime and database user that performed the change.  Then we have triggers on the production tables that writes records to the audit database if any values in the columns changes. Is that what you also want to achieve?

Comment: Yes, something like that. Only that my table it will not be identical(I will not have same number of columns) have Thanks!

Comment: As long as the columns in your source table exists (With identical types) in the destination table then you will be ok.  I am posting an example of my proposed solution.

Comment: Wow, nice. Now I need to figure out what I need to replace with my names.
Thanks for the help.
Can I contact you somewhere, where can I ask you what I must replacing and with what?
This is my first time when I interactions with SQL. Now I started to study a little bit SQL to understand the language.

Comment: No sorry, this forum is for questioning and answering and these guys are quite against sharing contact details.  So we will have to keep the comms here under this subject.

As you have probably noticed, this is quite intermediate SQL coding.  So some basic understanding of T-SQL is required to make all easier.  

If you have a test environment it is quite safe to play around with this script.  For that I would just drop the tables in that script so that you can run it repeatedly.  

The syntax you can add would be:

DROP TABLE [dbo].[SourceTable]
DROP TABLE [me].[DestinationTable]

Comment: I insert into SQL but at this command [me].[Destination Table] say that "The specified schema name "me" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it.
"?

Comment: You can run the following:

CREATE SCHEMA me

Comment: Hello Wiaan van Aswegen, your SQL code its working.
The only problem is that in "me.Destination Tabel" I have more rows than in table "dbo.Source Tabel" , but I want to have same number of rows. How I do that, it is possible?

Comment: The additional rows are added by either the UPDATE or DELETE triggers (check under "ActionType" column). This gives you a "change history". So removing those triggers will only add a record when you insert data.  If you want the change history but only see one record (for example the previous "version") then I can help you with some code that can return that.

Comment: This is what I want, in table "dbo.Source Tabel" you have one row in that you have information in columns "TextColumn", "ValueColumn" etc.
For start this information will be copied in table [me].[Destination Table], but when information into tabel"dbo.Source Tabel" for example in column "TextColumn" change from "test insert and update with no data change" with "Marius", to update in tabel [me].[Destination Table] only this information and not add new row. And so on for each column.Maybe this code does this and I do not know how to use it.
Can you explain me like to a "stupid man"? Sorry.

Comment: This code does not do this - It keeps a log of changes by writing a copy of the row to the destination table.  Looks like you want replication between the two tables.  A script like that will be quite hefty (Will have to write special code for each column.  I know SQL has replication (But between two databases as far as I know).   Maybe do some research on how to "sync" or replicate between tables.

Comment: The following thread related to replication between tables.. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/155311/how-to-do-live-replication-of-few-tables-in-sql-server-database